# Troubles With The Beginning

Tags: probability, statistics

The following is the question I'm having a bit of troubles starting:

Musicnotes.com sells sheet music in the following genres: rock jazz, new age, and country. An experiment consists of recording the preferred genre for the next customer, and the number of songs purchased (assume 5 is the max). Consider the following events: 
A = The next customer prefers rock.
B = The next customer prefers jazz and buys at least three songs.
C = The next customer buys at most two songs.
D = The next customer prefers country and buys one song.

Find the sample space for this experiment.

Then there are questions like Find these outcomes: A', etc which I can do once I figure out how to start this.

My thinking is to organize the info in a tree diagram but I'm stuck on how many "events" to stick together for want of a better term. For example would A1, A2, A3, A4, A5 be in the sample space aka at least part of it? What's with the 5? Like I'm a bit confused on that.

Any and all help would be appreciated greatly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample space is clearly the cartessian product of music preferred and songs purchased, by the next customer, which is to say: $$\{\mathrm{x, y, z}\}{\times}\{1,2,3,4,5\}$$

Where, for sake of brevity, we are using the enumeration: $\rm x$ for Rock Jazz, $\rm y$ for New Age, and $\rm z$ for Country.

So event $A$, "The next customer prefers rock", is $\{(\mathrm x,1), (\mathrm x,2), (\mathrm x,3), (\mathrm x,4), (\mathrm x,5)\}$

And so forth...